# openGL lighting rotates with camera

Tags: c++, opengl, lighting

I'm trying to build something simple for uni coursework and I've just tried to light it, but the lights seem to rotate with the camera, which is totally annoying...

I've pasted my code below using a pastebin (so that it doesn't stretch the page), but here's a little explanation too:

I added the lights in Display::Init (using the PoolLight class).
The camera is set up in Display::Resize. It's placed above the 'pool table' at (0, 0, 80), looking down (0, 0, -1), with the X axis being forward/up (1, 0, 0).

This simple movement and rotation of the camera adjusts the lights too, but not the geometry (or perhaps it adjusts the geometry, and not the lights, I'm not really sure).

I have read some of the other answers here concerning the same issue, but I don't really understand too well. I'm hoping someone can explain it to me in simpler terms, or maybe spot something obvious that I've accidentally excluded.

Anyway, here is the code:

[Main Display Class](http://pastebin.com/06Kmwk8Z)

PoolLight Class:

```
#include "PoolLight.h"
#include "Glut/glut.h"
#include "GL/gl.h"
#include "GL/glu.h"

PoolLight::PoolLight(GLenum lightNumber, GLenum lightType, float red, float green, float blue, bool distant, float posX, float posY, float posZ)
{
    this->lightNumber = lightNumber;
    this->lightType = lightType;

    color[0] = red; color[1] = green; color[2] = blue; color[3] = 1;
    position[0] = posX; position[1] = posY; position[2] = posZ; position[3] = (int) (!distant);
    glLightfv(lightNumber, lightType, color);
    glLightfv(lightNumber, GL_POSITION, position);

    enabled(true);
}


PoolLight::~PoolLight(void)
{
}

void PoolLight::setSpotlight(float angle, float attenuation, float dirX, float dirY, float dirZ) {
    glLightf(lightNumber, GL_SPOT_EXPONENT, angle);
    glLightf(lightNumber, GL_CONSTANT_ATTENUATION, attenuation);
    glLightf(lightNumber, GL_LINEAR_ATTENUATION, 0.0f);
    glLightf(lightNumber, GL_QUADRATIC_ATTENUATION, 0.0f);
    spotDirection[0] = dirX; spotDirection[1] = dirY; spotDirection[2] = dirZ;
    glLightfv(lightNumber, GL_SPOT_DIRECTION, spotDirection);
    glLightf(lightNumber, GL_SPOT_CUTOFF, 60);
}

void PoolLight::enabled(bool enabled) {
    if (enabled) glEnable(lightNumber);
    else glDisable(lightNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After changing the camera position, call `glLightfv(lightNumber, GL_POSITION, position)` again with the world-coordinates of the light.  Then draw the scene.